# Capturing and processing a live RTMP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live, rtmp

I'm trying to download a live stream (not a file) coming from a live camera feed available at the following website: http://www.dot.ca.gov/video/.

I used Wireshark for sniffing the TCP packets and was able to extract the RTMP parameters, but wasn't able to use them with FFMPEG/VLC for downloading / playing the stream on VLC (I guess I didn't construct the URL correctly).

for example, for the camera feed available [here](http://www.dot.ca.gov/d4/d4cameras/ct-cam-pop-E37_at_Lakeville_Rd.html/), I got the following parameters:

swfUrl: http://www.dot.ca.gov/research/its/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf

pageUrl: http://www.dot.ca.gov/d4/d4cameras/ct-cam-pop- N17_at_Saratoga_Rd.html

tcUrl: rtmp://wzmedia.dot.ca.gov:1935/D4
Play : E37_at_Lakeville_Rd.stream.

Is there a chance someone is familiar with this and can help with understanding how I can use the above for downloading the stream?

Thanks a lot! Yaniv

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg  -re -i "rtmp://wzmedia.dot.ca.gov:1935/D4"  -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -f flv  -y ~/save_stream.flv
```

"-i " means infile and "-y" means overwrite output files.

you can use ffmpeg -h to see it.

Comment: `-y` is used to automatically overwrite the output file in case it already exists.

Comment: Yeah, my expression has a  mistake@LordNeckbeard